# How to fix a race condition in Node.js/Express. Where my console will update correctly but my webpage doesn't update

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to build a simple webpage based on a couple API's. The issue i am running into is that some of my API's aren't finished getting their data before my page is loaded. Currently my code looks like the following:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {weather: null, headlocation: null, lat: null, long: null, imgLinks: null, WebLinks: null, imgLinksFl: null, restLat: null, restLong: null, error: null});

})


// Main Page
app.post('/', function (req, res) {

  city = req.body.city;
  weatherSearch();
  googleStuff();
  filckrSearch();
  zomatoStart();
  res.render('index', {weather: weatherText, headlocation: headLocationText, lat: latLocation, long: longLocation, imgLinks: imageLinks, WebLinks: websiteLinks, imgLinksFl: imageLinksFlick, restLat: latitudeRest, restLong: longitudeRest, error: null});

});
```

I want my page to render once all the data is collected. i have tried simple code for example (just a pseudocode example):

```
var flickrdone = ''; 
if (flickrdone = 'done'){
res.render.......
}
```

But even when i implement something like this my page is stuck loading and nothing ever happens. I am new to node/express and haven't fully understood app.post but no matter how much i read i can't seem to solve the problem. I understand my page is facing a race condition because my console can update correctly upon each search but my page doesn't update.  For example upon my first search if i type 'Sydney' then the console will update with the correct results from 'Sydney' but the page will not update. If i then do a second search of 'Perth' then the console will update with the correct results from 'Perth' but the page will not update. On the third search if type in 'Brisbane' then the console will update with the correct results from 'Brisbane' and then the page finally updates with the results from the first search of 'Sydney'. Can someone please explain what is going wrong and suggest how to fix it?

Comment: are `weatherSearch();
  googleStuff();
  filckrSearch();
  zomatoStart();` asynchronous functions (guessing they are) - without knowing what they do or what they return, my only suggestion is to learn about asynchronous callbacks / promises etc - there's no code to show how `weatherText`, `headLocationText` etc etc are even "populated" - so it's a guessing game for us

Comment: also, note, `if (flickrdone = 'done'){` would always be "truthy" anyway ... you'd probably want `if (flickrdone == 'done'){` - though, you don't want that either as that isn't how you use asynchronous code

Comment: Maybe this will start you off on the right path - https://pastebin.com/1C34KG0H

Comment: Even following promises i still get stuck waiting for the page to load

Comment: really? the issue I have is that the problem you experience is due to the functions I mentioned in the first comment - you're probably using them wrong, but without knowing what they do (i.e. the code) it's still a guessing game

Comment: @Sam as Jaromanda has mentioned and other will say too, this is a problem of handling asynchronous functions. In order to help you better share what `weatherSearch()`, `googleStuff()`, `filckrSearch()`, `zomatoStart()` do. By name of them It seems these are all asynchronous functions. and using `callback`, `promise request-resolve`, `async-await` or `generators` will resolve your problem.